# How to display name and email on every screen of app in flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, drawer

I displaying name and email (which are fetched from MongoDB) in drawer on home screen of app, now i want to display that drawer on every screen of my app, when i click on any page which are displayed on drawer then that page drawer should be similar to home drawer.

i am passing parameters too but it's giving me this error

**ERROR:**

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

here is my login code when user enter correct credentials then it will be redirect to home screen.

```
// this save() i am calling on login button 

Future save() async {

    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': user.username,
      'password': user.password

    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrl,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse){
        print(onResponse.data['User']);
        //var name=print(onResponse.data['User']['username']);
        print(onResponse.data['User']['designation']);
        print(onResponse.data['User']['TimeIn']);
  
         //**here i am passing values to  EmployeeNavigation which is my home** 
         Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmployeeNavigation(
        name:onResponse.data['User']['username'],     
        email:onResponse.data['User']['email'],
        designation:onResponse.data['User']['designation'],
        date:onResponse.data['User']['Date'],
        timeIn:onResponse.data['User']['TimeIn'],
        timeOut:onResponse.data['User']['TimeOut'],
        )));

      }).catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
        showAlertDialog(context);
    });
  }
```

this is my EmployeeNavigation code

```
class EmployeeNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  var name;
  var email;
  var designation;
  var date;
  var timeIn;
  var timeOut;
  EmployeeNavigation({this.name, this.email, this.designation, this.date, this.timeIn, this.timeOut, } );
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return EmployeeNavigationState(this.name,this.email,this.designation,this.date,this.timeIn,this.timeOut);
  }
}

class EmployeeNavigationState extends State<EmployeeNavigation> {

var name;
  var email;
  var designation;
  var date;

 EmployeeNavigationState(this.name,this.email, this.designation,this.date,this.timeIn, this.timeOut );
   bool valuefirst = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Image.asset("assets/image/company_logo.png",height: 140,width: 280,
       ),

       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue,size: 20),
       //leading: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.blue,),
       actions: <Widget>[
       IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
        Icons.notifications,
        color: Colors.blue,
        size:26
      ),
     
      
    )
    ],
    ),
    drawer:new  Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text(name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),  //here i am using name parameter
                accountEmail: new Text(email,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),  // here i am using email parameter
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor:
                  Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                name[0][0],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Request for leave'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.request_page),
              onTap: (){
           
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new RequestForLeave(name,email)  //here i am passing name and email parameters
                    )
                  );
              },
            ),
            new ExpansionTile(
              title: new Text('History'),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("My Attendance"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new MyAttendance()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                ),
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("Leaves"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new Leaves()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                )
                // Text("My Attendance"),
                // Text("Leaves"),
              ],
              leading: Icon(Icons.history,
            ),
            
            )],
        ),

      
    ),
 );
  }
}
```

and here is my RequestforLeave code where i pass parameters

```
import 'package:attendance_system_app/Admin_Navigation/AdminNavigation.dart';
import 'package:attendance_system_app/Employee_Navigation/EmployeeNavigation.dart';
import 'package:attendance_system_app/Leaves/Leaves.dart';
import 'package:attendance_system_app/My_Attendance/MyAttendance.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RequestForLeave extends StatefulWidget {
  var name;
  var email;
  RequestForLeave(name, email);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
     return _RequestForLeaveState(this.name,this.email);
     }
  
}

class _RequestForLeaveState extends State<RequestForLeave> {
  var name;
  var email;
_RequestForLeaveState(this.name,this.email);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Image.asset("assets/image/company_logo.png",height: 140,width: 280,
       ),
      
       //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue,size: 20),
       //leading: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.blue,),
       actions: <Widget>[
       IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
        Icons.notifications,
        color: Colors.blue,
        size:26
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        // do something
      },
      
    )
    ],
    ),
    drawer:new  Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text(name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                accountEmail: new Text(email,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor:
                  Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                name[0][0],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Request for leave'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.request_page),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new RequestForLeave(name,email)
                    )
                  );
              },
            ),
            new ExpansionTile(
              title: new Text('History'),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("My Attendance"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new MyAttendance()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                ),
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("Leaves"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new Leaves()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                )
                // Text("My Attendance"),
                // Text("Leaves"),
              ],
              leading: Icon(Icons.history,
            ),
            
            )],
        ),

      
    ),
      body:Center(
          child: Text(
        "Request for leave",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
      )),
      
      
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting correct values on EmployeeNavigation drawer but getting error when i click on Request for leave

here is error output

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is my drawer look like of home screen

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please help me to fix it, where i display same drawer on every screen of my app.

**-------------------- Updated------------------------------**

```
class EmployeeNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  var name;
  var email;
  var designation;
  var date;
  var timeIn;
  var timeOut;
  EmployeeNavigation({this.name, this.email, this.designation, this.date, this.timeIn, this.timeOut, } );
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return EmployeeNavigationState(this.name,this.email,this.designation,this.date,this.timeIn,this.timeOut);
  }
}

class EmployeeNavigationState extends State<EmployeeNavigation> {

// here is create Drawer widget

 Widget DrawerCode(){
   return Drawer(
     child: new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text(name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                accountEmail: new Text(email,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor:
                  Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                name[0][0],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Request for leave'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.request_page),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new RequestForLeave()
                    )
                  );
              },
            ),
            new ExpansionTile(
              title: new Text('History'),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("My Attendance"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new MyAttendance()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                ),
                ListTile(
                   title:new Text("Leaves"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined ),
                  onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>new Leaves()
                    )
                  );
              },
                 
                )
                // Text("My Attendance"),
                // Text("Leaves"),
              ],
              leading: Icon(Icons.history,
            ),
            
            )],
        ),

      
    );

   
 }


var name;
  var email;
  var designation;
  var date;

 EmployeeNavigationState(this.name,this.email, this.designation,this.date,this.timeIn, this.timeOut );
   bool valuefirst = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Image.asset("assets/image/company_logo.png",height: 140,width: 280,
       ),

       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue,size: 20),
       //leading: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.blue,),
       actions: <Widget>[
       IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
        Icons.notifications,
        color: Colors.blue,
        size:26
      ),
     
      
    )
    ],
    ),
    drawer:DrawerCode(),
 );
  }
}




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAqI2.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivpbu.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error showing is not related with the Drawer per say, it's related with the fact that you're passing a `NULL` into a `Text` widget that requires a valid string.

```
String variable = null;
Text(variable) <-- error

String variable = '';
Text(variable) <-- fine!
```

To me, it doesn't seem correct the approach you're taking. If you have 100 screens and you want to display the Drawer in every single one of them, you'll have 100 drawers. If you're into this approach, you should create a Drawer Widget file to avoid repeatness.

May I suggest you a different approach?

Lets say you have the following folder structure:

```
 Home Screen
    - Dashboard Screen
    - Customers Screen
    - Items Screen
```

Only the `Home Screen` has a drawer. The `Home Screen` will load all the child screens (Dashboard, Customers & Items) inside itself.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> 
{
    String appTitle = 'Dashboard';
    Widget appBody = DashboardScreen(); // By default

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              this.appTitle,
            ),
          ),
          body: this.appBody,
          drawer: YourDrawer()
        );
    }
}
```

And all you need now is a function to jump to another child screen whenever you want:

```
void jumpToScreen(String appTitle, Widget appBody)
{
    setState(()
    {
        this.appTitle = appTitle;
        this.appBody = appBody;
    });
}
```

You can also apply some logic to show different App Actions Buttons according to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I created a drawer widget in EmployeeNavigation file but can't access it to another file, and i can't create its separate file because i need name and email parameter which i am getting from login file and passing it to EmployeeNavigation file

Comment: and where i'll call this jumpToScreen funtion? can u please explain a bit more.

Comment: After you successfully login, you should save the `name` and `email` in SharedPreferences (google it), so you can access it everywhere in your app. The `jumpToScreen`, is a **suggestion**, but you'd add it below the function `Widget build`.

Comment: thank you so much, sharedpreference is working for me!